# How can i get all the text until a space don't come in Qstring?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qstring, qt4.8

Hello i want to get the ultil the space in line occur for example

[image: picture]

in the given picture  am able to get the whole string using getter method to my parent window but i dont want get the date time part
am currently getting

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw                    Sun Nov 1 20:29:30 2015
```

while i want get `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXw6OdVmMpw`

can anyone help me i used Qstring left right but i cant get it working properly.

Comment: This question is unintelligible. Please rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//QString Input holds your data...
QString Output = Input.section(' ', 0, 0);
```

`section` sees the string as fields seperated by a seperator character (`' '` in this case) and returns the section from the given start section (0) upto and including the end section (0).

Assuming the white space in your inputstring is really spaces, if it is not, change `' '` to the correct seperator character.

Comment: hi Thanks it working like charm :)

Comment: Wow...people voted this question down -4? Is it really that inappropriate of a question?